# Why is my textbox value not carrying over to a converted double?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a program with a GUI that reads a number of values from a textbox, adds them all to an array, and gets the sum and average. When I run the code with the textbox filled in with (for example) 92, theoretically that value should be picked up as a string from txtBox.Text, however when I step through the code it is showing txtBox.Text = "". This is causing this value, and all of the others, to some through as "". I am doing this with Windows Forms in VS.

Without putting all of my code on here, this is what I am creating:

```
//instantiate the new form
static Form1 form1 = new Form1();

//create the array to store values

public static double[] arr = new double[10];

//store the first value, as well as the rest, according to the textbox value
//get the value from the text and convert to double. **Note:** I need to have the "frm1" at the beginning of the txtBox.Text because otherwise I see an error that the textbox doesn't exist in the current context.

arr[0] = Convert.ToDouble(form1.txtBox.Text);
```

The above assignment of the Convert.ToDouble operation is storing the value in the txtBox.Text as "" and I am not sure why.

Comment: In the code you've shown, you create a **new** Form1, then immediately read the textbox value, which of course is empty. Are you trying to get the value from an _**existing**_ form1?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I believe it is in a different class, which is why I’m forced to add frm1.textBox.Text.

Answer (score 0):

You need an event to handle exactly when the value in the textbox should be retrieved. After a TextBox object is instantiated, its Text property is always empty.

Comment: Thank you. I have a number of the fields instantiated. I then run a method to get the values once Enter button is clicked. That is when I get the value of each text box, however it still comes through as “”.

Comment: @SantiagoSentu Can you share me a snipped of your code?